# python behave html formatter does not generate Spanish characters correctly on HTML

Tags: python, plugins, pip, bdd, python-behave

I am new to behave and I am doing a simple test.

- behave 1.2.6
- python 3.11.3
- behave-html-formatter 0.9.10
- windows 10
- visual studio code and powershell

I have 1 features file with very basic spanish language and 1 file with the steps also very simple

I run in the visual studio code terminal the command
`behave.exe .\features`
and the result is correct and everything looks good.

for example in terminal I see:
Característica: Pantalla de logín de mi sistema

but when I run the command
`behave.exe .\features --format behave_html_formatter:HTMLFormatter -o report_tutorial.html`
the generated html does not paint well the characters like á é í ó ú

for example Caracter�stica: Pantalla de log�n de mi sistema